# How do I submit data with Dojo DateTextBox after selecting a date

Tags: dojo

I'm trying to make a DateTextBox that submits data once a date is selected. To do that I have this code: `<form action="timecard/setViewDate" method="post" id="timespan" dojoType="dijit.form.Form">
<input type="text" name="calendar" value="2009-09-28" id="calendar" dojoType="dijit.form.DateTextBox" onchange="doTimechangeSubmit"  />
</form>` and the onchange function is: `function doTimechangeSubmit()
{
    var thisdialog = new dijit.Dialog({ title: "Please Wait...", content: "We are wasting some time.", id: 'stupidWasteOfTime'});
    dojo.body().appendChild(thisdialog.domNode);
    thisdialog.startup();
    thisdialog.show();
    setTimeout("dojo.byId('timespan').submit();",1000);
    dojo.byId('timespan').submit(); 
}`

I have this function because without waiting a bit the value I receive is the date the widget starts with. I hate this and I'm just waiting for a slow response to break it.

My want is to hook the submit function in a place that guarantees I get the value the user actually selected. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: what version of Dojo are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in Dojo 1.4.  Refer to ticket [#9566](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/9566).

Answer (score 0):

Change `dojo.byId('timespan').submit();` to `dijit.byId('timespan').submit();`

For an explanation read [this](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-3-programmatic-dijit-and-dojo/functions-used-everywhere/dojo-byid).

Comment: Nope doesn't do anything different I still need the Timeout to slow down the submission for the dijit's logic.

Comment: Hmm.  That's confusing.  Actually, both are valid yet they do slightly different things.  The first calls submit() on the DOM FORM element -- which should work fine -- and the latter calls submit() on the dijit.form.Form element which ends up calling the same native method but does some validity checking.

Comment: er, I meant the latter calls submit on the dijit.form.Form *widget* object, as opposed to the DOM element.